# json4s: cross field extraction

Tags: scala, json4s

json4s `extract` JsonAST based on per-type rules defined in `DefaultFormats` and `CustomSerializer`.

Sometimes I want to have cross field extraction. For example, given a json string `{"a": 1, "b": 2}`, I want to set the value of `b` into `a+b`. I can do:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.JsonAST._

case class A(a: Int, b: Int)

case object ACustomSerializer extends CustomSerializer[A](
    format =>
    ({
        case jo: JObject =>
            val a = (jo \ "a").extract[Int]
            val b = (jo \ "b").extract[Int] + a
            A(a, b)
    }, Map())
)

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + ACustomSerializer

parse("""{"a": 1, "b": 2}""").extract[A] // A(1,3)
```

However, if `case class A` has many other fields, it becomes hard to write rule for all of them.

```
case class A(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int)

case object ACustomSerializer extends CustomSerializer[A](
    format =>
    ({
        case jo: JObject =>
            val a = (jo \ "a").extract[Int]
            val b = (jo \ "b").extract[Int] + a
            val c = ...
            val d = ...
            A(a, b, c, d)
    }, Map())
)
```

They could have been handled by `DefaultFormats` or other `CustomSerializer` if we don't want to have "cross field extraction" for field `b`. Things get worse if the case class is actually large.

Is there a way to write rule for special fields only, and leave the rest handled by `DefaultFormats` or `CustomSerialzer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is best to parse data as-is and then process afterwards (in order to maintain [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

In this case it looks like this:

```
val a = parse("""{"a": 1, "b": 2}""").extract[A] // A(1,2)

a.copy(b = a.a + a.b) // A(1,3)
```

In more complex cases the layout of the processed data will differ from the parsed data so you will need a second `case class` that describes raw data and a function to convert this to the processed format. While this may seem cumbersome, it will make the code easier to understand and more amenable to modification.